# React-Native how to use KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native, keyboard

Both the header and the chat container move-up when I start typing some message.

I have tried to use KeyboardAvoidingView inside my view container, however, it did not work, I'm not sure if the KeyboardAvoidingView is the best solution to control the keyboard inside the view and not familiar with it.

Below is my code:

```
render() {
const { myName, user, nome, message } = this.props;
return (
  <View style={STYLES.main}>

    <Animatable.View
      style={STYLES.container}
      animation={FADEIN}
      easing='ease-in'
      duration={1000}
    >
      <RenderHeader3 press={() => Actions.detalhes()} hcolor={'#298CFF'} color={'#FFF'} text={nome} icon={null} isize={null} />

      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingTop: 5 }}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          behavior={null}
          keyboardVerticalOffset={60}
        >
          <ListView
            enableEmptySections
            dataSource={this.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
          />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>

      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#1A1C27', padding: 10 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 4 }}>
          <TextInput
            style={[STYLES.titleTxt, { color: '#000', backgroundColor: '#FFF', borderRadius: 40, paddingLeft: 13, paddingRight: 10 }]}
            multiline
            value={message}
            onChangeText={(texto) => this.props.modificaMensagem(texto)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 10 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              borderRadius: 40,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              backgroundColor: '#298CFF',
              paddingRight: 2
            }}
            activeOpacity={0.5}
            onPress={() => this.props.createChat(myName, user, nome, message)}
          >
            <CustomIcon
              name='paper-plane'
              size={25}
              color='#FFF'
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

    </Animatable.View>

  </View>
);
```

}
}

[image: Component before start typing]
[image: The Header and the chat scrollView moved-up]
[image: result with behavior='height']

Comment: KeyboardAvoidingView has 3 types of behavior enum('height', 'position', 'padding') but you set it to null

Comment: Hi, finding the same issue. I have it sorted out for iOS, using KeyboardAwareScrollView, but for Android I am using KeyboardAvoidingView and can't somehow define a margin between the keyboard and the textinput. Did you find any solution or workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make this changes

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          behavior="height"
          keyboardVerticalOffset={60}
        >
```

[source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview#behavior)

Comment: hi @VinilPrabhu, did not work, not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've attached a new image with the result by setting the behavior to 'height'

Comment: @GustavoMenezes `KeyboardAvoidingView` should be root tag, and all other elements should come inside of it, like scrollview, textbox etc

Comment: you code should be almost like [this](https://snack.expo.io/@vinil.prabhu/keyboardavoidingview)

Comment: I did as per your example. but still not working, Do you think I have to change something into the android manifest file?

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` add this line to your manifest file

Comment: [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11681#issuecomment-277645925)

Answer (score -2):

> KeyboardAvoidingView has 3 types of behavior `enum('height','position','padding')` but you set it to null in your code.
>   Secondly you have not added `KeyboardAvoidingView` in with `TextInput` component

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          behavior={'height'}
          keyboardVerticalOffset={60}
        >
```